Does it matter which screw I use for wire connections on a series of outlets?
I wanted to know if it was okay to cross the wires on outlets that appear to be set up in series.  What I mean is on the first outlet in the series, from the cable coming from the electric panel, the black wire goes to the bottom screw and the white goes to the top screw and the other cable going to the other outlet, the black wire goes to the top screw and the white wire goes to the bottom screw?  The black wires are both screwed into the copper side and the white wires are both screwed on the silver side.
I don't like to touch anything electric but my spouse decided to change almost all of the receptacles in the house while I was at work.  I had to correct some issues and now things work as they are supposed to, even the sockets that are connected to light switches.  I'm proud of my work and what I've learned, but I realized that I put the receptacles back in the wall without checking if I crossed the wires on some of the receptacles.  My family is sleeping and I don't want to wake them but I also don't want a fire to break out during the night.  I called an electrician to come and certify the work or fix what's wrong but until then I'm pretty stressed.

What you're referring to as "series" is actually "daisy-chaining". True "series" would be: power comes into the brass hot side of the first outlet, then the first outlet silver neutral side is wired to the brass hot side of the 2nd outlet, silver neutral of 2nd outlet wired to brass hot of 3rd outlet, etc. Something would have to be plugged into and turned on in each outlet for anything to get power, and everything would get only a slice of power depending on its resistance. True "series" is never done in wiring outlets and is a major code violation. Continued...

"Daisy-chaining" is a parallel wiring scheme, where the power comes into the brass hot of the first outlet, then continues to 2nd outlet's brass hot, then 3rd outlet's brass hot. Same for the silver neutrals. Each outlet gets full power from the power and neutral "bus" wires. Daisy-chaining is code-compliant and the way most outlet runs are wired.

It sounds like you're crossing hots and neutrals.  On your typical outlet the screws on each side are both "sided," i.e. hots on one side (often brass screws) and neutrals on the other side (silver screws).  While mixing and matching can physically be done, it's bad practice to mix and match, and may violate code (others may know better).

@Huesmann, Thank you for the response.  No, I don't mean crossing them in that manner, all of my hot wires are on the brass side and my neutral wires are on the silver side.  I mean if you have a cable coming in from the fuse box and another cable going out to another receptacle, the first cable, the black wire is connected to the top brass screw and the white wire is connected to the bottom silver screw and the cable going out has the black wire going to the bottom brass screw and the white wire is connected to the top silver screw.

What is top and bottom anyway?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNj75gJVxcE

@JayFou as long as the outlet isn't split (connecting tab intact), that wouldn't ordinarily be a problem.  Still, it's not my preferred arrangement.

To address the core question: "will it go on fire?"  No. If you miswired things at this level, then you might get an immediate bang, might trip out a breaker or two, but fires are caused by bad workmanship, not by mistakes.

With ordinary duplex receptacles, it doesn't matter. The top and bottom of each side are connected together electrically, unless the connecting piece between them is deliberately removed, which is generally done only for "half switched" receptacles (so that the switch controls one receptacle, such as a switch for a plug-in room light or a garbage disposal, and the other receptacle is always on) or for Multi-Wire Branch Circuits (MWBC).
There is one very important exception: GFCI. With GFCI, the top and bottom are independent. One set of connections is for line (i.e., incoming power) and the other is for load (providing GFCI-protected power to another receptacle). In that situation, if you "cross the wires" then you will be violating code, as the neutral and hot wires would not be paired correctly. However, if you did that then you would find that the GFCI would either immediately trip or simply not work at all.
FYI, for ordinary receptacles you can also pigtail the wires - i.e., connect the two black hot wires together with a third short black wire (the pigtail) and connect the pigtail to the receptacle. Do the same with the white neutral wires. Everything will work just fine - if crossing the wires was a problem this would be a problem too. But most people just use the second set of screws to avoid the small bit of extra work of making pigtails.

Hello, thank you for taking the time to respond.  This is good news.  On the silver side, the connector is there and in some cases, the connector on the bronze side is there.  Only in the case of a red wire (switch) did I remove the connector.  My understanding is that the residual electricity would flow either from the bottom screw to the top or visa versa and wouldn't change anything.  But again, I'm not an electrician and assumptions can be wrong so I wanted to make sure.

If, by what you mean by "crossed the wires", you mean switched black (hot) and white (neutral), then yes, this is a problem. Not in the sense that you'll burn the house down but in the sense that someone could get shocked you have an old appliance with a problem or in some other circumstances.
This can easily be checked without opening up the outlets. Purchase a three-light outlet tester, such as this at Home Depot (just an example). These can be purchased at any hardware store or large department store. Go to each outlet and plug it in. If it indicates "hot/neutral reversed", then you did switch wires, either in that outlet, one feeding that outlet. Fix these as soon as possible.
Note that if an "open Ground" is reported (missing or disconnected green/bare wire), then the tester will not be able to detect reversed hot/neutral. In fact, a missing ground would make a reversed hot/neutral even more dangerous. Fix this too.

Hello, thank you for taking the time to respond.  Yes, I used a three light tester and they all registered as okay.  What I mean is that there are two silver screws, two bronze screws, and a ground.  So far as I can tell the ground is fine, even according to the tester.  What I mean is the white wire from one cable is connect to the top silver screw and the black wire is connected to the bottom bronze screw.  The next cable going to the other receptacle has the white wire to the bottom silver screw and the black wire connected to the top bronze screw.

@JayFou Assuming the metal tabs on the sides of the outlet were not broken off, there is no difference between the top and bottom screw on a side. They are electrically connected together and can be used interchangeably.

Picture is worth a thousand words. And I understand your confusion..
Electricians often describe outlets as wired 'in series' when what they mean is they didn't use pigtails:
This is a bunch of outlets wired in parallel IE with pigtails : Figure 1
And is functionally the same as this wiring in 'series' which is still in parallel, just not using pigtails, and instead using the outlets to connect the wires.  You can swap red wires around with other red wires, or black with other black no impact on performance (assuming you aren't using GFCI):
 Figure 2
It can cause all of the outlets connected to this circuit to stop working if one of the outlets goes bad/is removed... But that is only because the outlet is being used to connect the red to red and the black to black as opposed to using a pigtail... It is much faster to wire this way, and is almost as good as wiring in pigtails (though it does make it harder to figure out which outlet went bad.)
NOTE: it doesn't matter which wire goes to which screw as long as load is connected to load, and neutral to neutral. They metal strip electrically connects the wire and makes this circuit identical to the top one (with pigtails), as long as none of the outlets break/you don't remove the metal tab.
This is what non electricians (but CS/CE/EE, and or anyone with experience with electronics) think you mean when you say 'series'. This one is bad and will not work:
 Figure 3
Power has to flow thru each outlet before it is available for use by the next outlet. This means that you need something plugged into each outlet for it to work, and all of the devices will have less than 120V. This is bad, don't do it.
As long as you wired your outlets like Figure 1 or Figure 2, with neutral to neutral, and load to load you are good to go.

Receptacles (AKA "outlets") are never wired in series. Unless you have a duplex receptacle wherein the bridge between the top and bottom screws has been removed, it is totally arbitrary whether any given wire is attached to the top or bottom screw.

Hello, yes, from what I understand, Running receptacles in parallel is the better option, but I'm pretty sure that in my house, the circuits are run in series.  I say this because I don't see any "pigtails" in the boxes, almost all of the receptacles have 2 black (or one black and one red in the event of a switch), and two white, and I've disconnected some receptacles and others have stopped working.  Again, I'm not an electrician and all of my knowledge is from what I've learned in the last week so I could be very wrong.

I removed the connector when there was a switch involved but I didn't remove the connector if the receptacle seemed to b wired in a series.

@JayFou even without pigtails, your receptacles are still wired in parallel. If they really were wired in series (using the technical definition of series wiring in a circuit), then none of them would work.

@JayFou: See Triplefault's comment on your question above. What you call "series" is not what electricians mean by that word. In household wiring, switches are in series with the thing they switch and fuses / circuit breakers are in series with the whole circuit they protect, and those are pretty much the only series connections (in the standard sense) you'll ever see. In particular, all power sockets on a circuit are always connected in parallel to each other, since otherwise unplugging one socket would disconnect all of them.
